# VSCode cannot import Rascal modules of the same project

Tags: visual-studio-code, rascal

I have a Rascal/Flybytes project in VSCode. When I define two modules, even if they are in the same folder, they cannot import each other. Consider the files `A.rsc` and `B.rsc` in the same folder:

```
module A

int a() = 2;
```

```
module B

import A; //line 3

int b() {
    return a(); //line 6
}
```

Then I get 3 errors in module B:

For line 3:

> Reference to name `A` cannot be resolved

> Undefined module `A`

And for line 6:

> Undefined  `a`

When simply opening a shell and importing `B`, everything works fine.
The issue also only happens for local modules; importing a Flybytes module, for example, works flawlessly.

What is the problem here? What can I do to make VScode see local modules?

In case it matters, I'm on a Mac with Apple Silicon. I have noticed that the ARM port of VSCode is a bit buggy sometimes.

Comment: The information in the file `./META-INF/RASCAL.MF` is leading in this case, and the location of the A.rsc and B.rsc files in the filesystem. Can you share those with us?

Comment: Using `import util::Reflective; newRascalProject(..)` will generate a working setup for you.

Comment: `Manifest-Version: 0.0.1
Project-Name: flybytes-evalgen
Source: src/main/rascal
Require-Libraries: |lib://flybytes|
`
The A and B files are in `src/main/rascal`.

Comment: @JurgenVinju I just used `newRascalProject` to create a new project, added one module (in the same folder) and tried importing that in the Main module, and had the same problem again.

Comment: Is the flybytes-evalgen project in a folder of the same name?

Comment: Yes, project is located in that folder

Comment: Better have a call or chat on slack about this this week. This should just work. We all use it like this. some of us have arm processors.

Comment: I just pushed everything (including all garbage that I didn't clean up) to Github: https://github.com/bys1/flybytes-evalgen
In case this helps you to find anything that might be wrong let me know

Comment: That is very helpful. I cloned the project and opened it in VScode. After changing the B file (added a space) and saving, there was a type-check run that reported no failures. Also hyperlinks for the a function and the A module worked. So, I'm baffled. Could it be that some stale files are being used to report the errors. Please remove your `target` folder completely and try again? Or open the project in a new workspace as well?

Comment: I just created an empty folder and used `newRascalProject(|cwd:///apekop|)` to create a new project in that folder. Added a module `Test` and tried importing it in the `Main` module. Same errors. So it happens with every project I create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the folder was not properly opened in the VScode Explorer. Opening the folder there fixed the problem. I never knew this was necessary, but apparently it is not possible to just open a single Rascal file in VScode without having it spit tons of errors.

VScode is a bit weird in opening files as well - sometimes opening a file/folder just doesn't work and a restart is needed to fix this. But that is a VScode bug and not related to this issue.